# How to use Mahalanobis Distance in libfacerec while preforming PCA in OPENCV v2 API?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition, pca

I am working on a Face Recognition Project and I am using libfacerec. While predicting the labels the library uses norm() which calculates the absolute difference. How can I use Mahalanobis Distance to improve my accuracy?
OpenCV2 has a function:

```
double Mahalanobis(InputArray vec1, InputArray vec2, InputArray icovar)
```

which requires me to calculate icovar by using

```
void calcCovarMatrix(InputArray samples, OutputArray covar, OutputArray mean, int flags, int ctype=CV_64F)
```

but, this function expects samples to be stored either as separate matrices or as rows/columns of a single matrix. I don't know how to provide data to this function, i.e. how to make samples separate matrices or as rows of a single matrix. Please Help.
I wish to change the following code:

```
int Eigenfaces::predict(InputArray _src) const {
// get data
Mat src = _src.getMat();
// project into PCA subspace
Mat q = project(_eigenvectors, _mean, src.reshape(1,1));
double minDist = numeric_limits<double>::max();
int minClass = -1;
for(unsigned int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < _projections.size(); sampleIdx++) {
    //Change Here------------------------------------------------
    Mat icovar;
    Mat mean;
    calcCovarMatrix(Mat(),icovar,mean,CV_COVAR_SCRAMBLED);
    double dist = Mahalanobis(q, sampleIdx, icovar);
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    //double dist = norm(_projections[sampleIdx], q, NORM_L2);
    if(dist < minDist) {
        minDist = dist;
        minClass = _labels[sampleIdx];
    }
}
return minClass;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

First of all this. From my personal experience I can tell you, that for a PCA the distance metric doesn't really have any significant impact on the recognition rate. I know some papers report it, but I can't acknowledge it on my image databases. As for your question on how to calculate the Mahalanobis distance. There's a close relationship between a PCA and the Mahalanobis distance, see "Improving Eigenfaces" at http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_5/page_5.html, which is also given in [1]. Just for sake of completeness, the project this post refers to is given at: https://github.com/bytefish/libfacerec.

### Code

Without any further testing I would rewrite the cognotics thing into:

```c
int cv::Eigenfaces::predict(InputArray _src) const {
  // get data
  Mat src = _src.getMat();
  // project into PCA subspace
  Mat q = subspace::project(_eigenvectors, _mean, src.reshape(1,1));
  double minDist = numeric_limits<double>::max();
  int minClass = -1;
  for(int sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < _projections.size(); sampleIdx++) {
    Mat diff0, diff1;
    // perform element wise multiplication and division
    multiply(q - _projections[sampleIdx], q - _projections[sampleIdx], diff0);
    divide(diff0.reshape(1,1), _eigenvalues.reshape(1,1), diff1);
    double dist = sum(diff1).val[0];
    if(dist < minDist) {
      minDist = dist;
      minClass = _labels[sampleIdx];
    }
  }
  return minClass;
}
```

### References

[1] Moghaddam, B. and Pentland, A. "Probabilistic Visual Learning for Object Representation" In *Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on* Vol. 19, No. 7. (1997), pp. 696-710

Comment: 1. I have already went over the whole series at  http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series, but that was using the old API. I just wanted to use the use API to calculate the Mahalanobis distance. 2. I deliberately used the tags so that I can get a reply from you. Sorry, I forgot to mention the link to your project. 3. If we can calculate the Mahalanobis distance by the method you are using here, then what is the use of the Mahalanobis function which OpenCV provides?

Comment: I will try this code and let you know if it works and whether or not it gives any improvements.

Comment: It's giving me worse results. Are you sure that is the correct way to calculate the Mahalanobis distance?

Comment: I've added the relevant publication in my post, please see [1] Eq. 7 for a derivation of the equation. If you spot an error in the code above, feel free to correct it. If you spot an error in the publication ([1]), also feel free to contact the authors. However, I never said a Mahalabonis distance performs better.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've been doing it for my assignments is to flatten each image.  So if the image is 24x24 I reshape it to 1x1024.

Then I stack the 2 images I wish to compare into one array.  So now you have a 2x1024 matrix/array.

I put that 2x1024 into calcCovarMatrix() to get the covariance array (using the COVAR_ROWS flag).  Then you invert it using invert().

Then you pass your two images and your inverted covariance into Mahalanobis()